# Bug (?) on selecting knots on scipy.insterpolate's splrep function

Tags: python, scipy

I have this question regarding scipy's splrep function, which I think is a bug, so I'll post every piece of code so you can reproduce it on your computers. Suppose I want to find the b-spline representation of some data, say, the one obtained by the following code, which creates a dataset as a mixture of ten gaussians with some addeded noise:

```
import numpy as np
# First we define the number of datapoints:
ndata = 100
x = np.arange(0,1,1./np.double(ndata))
means = np.random.uniform(0,1,10)
y = 0.0
for i in range(len(means)):
    y = y+np.exp(-(x-means[i])**2./0.01)
# We add some noise to obtain the data:
data = y + np.random.normal(0,0.05,len(y))
```

Which should see like this:
[image: Noisy data and the true curve (mixture of gaussians)]
Now, let's use splrep and splev functions to obtain the b-spline representation of this curve:

```
from scipy.interpolate import splrep,splev
# First define the number of knots. Let's put, say, 10 knots:
nknots = 10
# Now we crate the array of knots:
knots = np.arange(x[1],x[len(x)-1],(x[len(x)-1]-x[1])/np.double(nknots))
tck = splrep(x,data,t=knots)
fit = splev(x,tck)
```

If you plot everything up to here, everything seems ok:
[image: Fit with b-splines]
However, there are problems with certain combinations of the number of datapoints and number of knots. For example, if you try the above code with `ndata = 1931` and `nknots = 796`, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 465, in
splrep raise _iermess[ier][1](_iermess[ier][0])
ValueError:     Error on input data
```

This is giving me problems because the above code is not automatizable. I'm playing with datasets which have ~19000 datapoints, where a `while` cycle with `try` and `except` can be very computationally demanding. So my questions are:

1. Can you reproduce this problem? And if you can...
2. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Just a remark `x[len(x)-1]` can be written as `x[-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

I created a way around the problem. It probably has to do with a low number of datapoints to fit between two knots, so what I did was to replace the line where I create the number of knots with:

```
idx_knots = (np.arange(1,len(x)-1,(len(x)-2)/np.double(nknots))).astype('int')
knots = x[idx_knots]
```

In that way, I ensure that there are enough datapoints between the knots because I play with the indices of the x vector.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the knots directly (through the `t` parameter), you can use the `s` parameter.
The `s` parameter controls the smoothness of the spline. It does it by increasing the number of knots until the condition

```
sum((w * (y - g))**2,axis=0) <= s
```

is satisfied (g is the smoothed spline representation, w are the weights).