# How to set manual knots in scipy.interpolate.splprep in case of periodic boundary conditions?

Tags: python, scipy, bspline

or

### Why `splprep` does not work with its own knots?

I am trying to figure out how to set the knots in `scipy.interpolate.splprep`.
In a non-periodic case I succeed, i.e. I can reproduce [this SE example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14533908/803359).

In case of periodic boundary conditions (PBC) I have a problem, though. Here  `scipy.interpolate.splprep` doesn't even work with its own knots as this example shows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splev, splrep
import scipy

print "my scipy version: ", scipy.__version__

srate = 192000.
freq = 1200.

timeList = [ i / srate for i in range( int( srate / freq + 1 ) ) ]
signal = np.fromiter( ( np.sin( 2 * np.pi * freq * t ) for t in timeList ), np.float )

spl = splrep( timeList, signal, per=1 )
knots = spl[0]
spl = splrep( timeList, signal, t=knots, per=1 )
```

gives:

```
my scipy version:  1.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splrevtest.py", line 15, in <module>
      spl = splrep( timeList, signal, t=knots, per=1 )
  File "/somepath/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-1.0.0-py2.7-linux-/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-1.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 289, in splrep
      res = _impl.splrep(x, y, w, xb, xe, k, task, s, t, full_output, per, quiet)
  File "/somepath/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-1.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py", line 514, in splrep
      raise _iermess[ier][1](_iermess[ier][0])
  ValueError: Error on input data
```

Moreover, if you plot the first and the last knots like:

```
print timeList[-1]
print knots[:4]
print knots[-4:]
```

you get

```
>> 0.000833333333333
>> [-1.56250000e-05 -1.04166667e-05 -5.20833333e-06  0.00000000e+00]
>> [0.00083333 0.00083854 0.00084375 0.00084896]
```

meaning that there are six dots out of the actual data range, three before and three after. This is probably OK as we have PBC and the knots are identical to knots inside the data range modulus the period, but strange anyway. (BTW, the example does not even work when setting `per=0`.) Moreover, setting points outside the data range fails if I set the dots manually. It works, even with `per=1`, if the dots are well inside the data range. Like e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splev, splrep
import scipy

x = np.linspace( 0, 1, 120 )
timeList = np.linspace( 0, 1, 15 )
signal = np.fromiter( ( np.sin( 2 * np.pi * t +.3 ) for t in timeList ), np.float )
signal[ -1 ] -= .15
myKnots=np.linspace( .05, .95, 8 )
spl = splrep( timeList, signal, t=myKnots, per=1 )
fit = splev(x,spl)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( timeList, signal, marker='o' )
ax.plot( x, fit , 'r' )
for i in myKnots:
    ax.axvline( i )
plt.show()
```

providing:

[image: knot test]

wehre one can also see that the last point is ignored in PBC.

So what is `scipy.interpolate.splprep` actually doing here, and why is it not accepting a similar knot construction for manual set knots if `per=1`. Is it a bug?

I hope the answer to the last question is 'no', as otherwise I'd be wrong asking this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make `splrep` work with your own knots, you should change:

```
spl = splrep(timeList, signal, t=knots, per=1)
```

to use the interior knots:

```
spl = splrep(timeList, signal, t=knots[4:-4], per=1)
```

This interface isn't so intuitive but it appears in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) (albeit under the `task` parameter and not under `t`) (my emphasis):

> If task=-1 find the weighted least square spline for a given set of knots, t. **These should be interior knots** as knots on the ends will be added automatically.

The additional knots are also documented there. This is consistent with the general connection between the number of knots and the number of coefficients: `number_of_knots = number_of_coefficients + degree + 1`.

The last point in the PBC construction is ignored (as shown in your figure) because the periodic definition requires that the value of the last point in the period be equal to the first. This is documented under the `per` parameter where it says  `"Values of y[m-1] and w[m-1] are not used."` (again, not a very intuitive interface I guess, but that's probably how the Fortran code was implemented).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Ignoring `y[m-1]` etc actually seems logic to me. I wasn't surprised, just added it to the question for completeness. The first part, though, is---as you say---not so intuitive.

Comment: Whis is number_of_coefficients not connected to degree? degree tells you number of nodes per element

Comment: And any idea how to link this to basis_element?