# Least-square spline interpolation forcing interpolant to pass through specific points

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, interpolation, spline

I am having issues in implementing some less-than-usual interpolation problem. I have some (x,y) data points scattered along some curve which a priori I don't know, and I want to reconstruct this curve at my best, interpolating my point with min square error. I thought of using `scipy.interpolate.splrep` for this purpose (but maybe there are better options you would advise to use). The additional difficulty in my case, is that I want to constrain the spline curve to pass through some specific points of my original data. I assume that playing with knots and weights could make the trick, but I don't know how to do so (I am procrastinating avoidance of spline interpolation theory besides basic fitting procedures). Also, for some undisclosed reasons, when I try to setup knots in my `splrep` I get the same error of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533908/bug-on-selecting-knots-on-scipy-insterpolates-splrep-function), which keeps complicating things. The following is my sample code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as spi
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Some surrogate sample data
f = lambda x : x**2 - x/2.
x = np.arange(0.,20.,0.1)
y = f(4*(x + np.random.normal(size=np.size(x))))

# I want to use spline interpolation with least-square fitting criterion, making sure though that the spline starts
# from the origin (or in general passes through a precise point of my dataset). 
# In my case for example I would like the spline to originate from the point in x=0. So I attempted to include as first knot x=0... 
# but it won't work, nor I am sure this is the right procedure...

fy = spi.splrep(x,y)
fy = spi.splrep(x,y,t=fy[0])
yy = spi.splev(x,fy)

plt.plot(x,y,'-',x,yy,'--')
plt.show()
```

which despite the fact I am even passing knots computed from a first call of `splrep`, it will give me:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 289, in splrep
    res = _impl.splrep(x, y, w, xb, xe, k, task, s, t, full_output, per, quiet)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py", line 515, in splrep
    raise _iermess[ier][1](_iermess[ier][0])
ValueError: Error on input data
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the weights argument of `splrep`: can give these points you need fixed very large weights. This is a workaround for sure, so keep an eye on the fit quality and stability.

Comment: Ok it works. However, ideal would be to also have the spline interpolant match derivatives at the extremes points. MATLAB for example has such an option in the [`spline(x,y,xq)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) function just providing `y` of `len(x)+2` where `y[0]` and `y[-1]` (resp. `y(1)` and `y(end)` in MATLAB notation) are the derivatives at those points. Can I easily achieve this in python as well?

Comment: Thanks. I knew of the `BSPline.from_derivatives` and `splprep` but as you pointed out, combined with `spline` fitting are not available at the moment in `scipy`. So I need to sort out an alternative solution. What if I set knots in my original problem? How do I combine the knots with the weights? Is it straight forward?

Answer (score 0):

Setting high weights for specific points is indeed a working solution as suggested by @ev-br. In addition, because there is no direct way to match derivatives at the extrema of the curve, the same rationale can be applied in this case as well. Say you want the derivative in `y[0]` and `y[-1]` match the derivative of your data points, then you add large weights also for `y[1]` and `y[-2]`, i.e.

```
weights = np.ones(len(x))
weights[[0,-1]] = 100  # Promote spline interpolant through first and last point
weights[[1,-2]] = 50   # Make spline interpolant derivative tend to derivatives at first/last point
fy = spi.splrep(x,y,w=weights,s=0.1)
yy = spi.splev(x,fy)
```